# order by Time using current time?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select-query

I haven't knowledge about DBA .
I am a ios developer i have one question for DBA .

```
`SELECT StartDate,Subject
 FROM tbl_Calendar
 WHERE StartDate BETWEEN ` date('2017-04-25') AND ('2017-04-26')
```

[image: This is My Table Data]

Ex : 1

if current time is **13:30:00**

give me this order **3,4,5,2,1**

Ex : 2

if current time is **12:35:00**

give me this order **2,3,4,5,1**

Ex : 3

if current time is **11:35:00**

give me this order **1,2,3,4,5**

This is my Table sql :

```
  CREATE TABLE `tbl_Calendar` (
    `StartDate` datetime,
    `Subject`   ntext
  );
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: what's the reasoning behind this ordering? absolute difference?

Comment: This is a event sedule so if current time is 12:30 it means 12:00 work on going (print 1st )and next work is 1:00 (print  second)   and next or next  and last work is finish

Comment: If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering is effectively undefined (however much it looks reproducible). If you _want_ a specific order, add an appropriate `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Just to clarify if this is to be used for **event schedule** why would you require the values 2 and 1 for your example 1. As its already past that time.

Comment: @Joby  it's client requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` in your `ORDER BY` like this:

```
    SELECT 
        StartDate, Subject
    FROM   
        tbl_Calendar
    WHERE  
        StartDate BETWEEN DATE ('2017-04-25') AND ('2017-04-26')
    ORDER  BY 
        CASE WHEN ((StartDate < DATETIME('now', 'localtime')) AND (StartDate <> (SELECT StartDate FROM tbl_Calendar WHERE  StartDate < DATETIME ('now', 'localtime') ORDER  BY StartDate desc limit 1))) THEN DATETIME (StartDate, '+1 day') ELSE StartDate END;
```

The subselect inside `CASE` will ignore the running event record and change only the previous ones.

Comment: @HarshilKotecha No problem. Glad to help you.

Comment: current time stamp give 13:31 please check . how to set time zone

Comment: i think this is good StartDate < datetime('now','localtime') ?

Comment: if you knowledge which **question  headline** good please suggest or edit

Comment: now new query not  work conver datetime to timestamp ?

Comment: datetime('now','localtime')  this function give me a date or time

Comment: i just give idea but i have not know it is possible or not

Comment: `datetime('now','localtime')` worked fine for me. It gives you the date and time of your timezone.

Comment: No problem I get time local timestamp from iOS Swift and add in this query

Comment: TimeZone is not fix. Because this app for all Asia  . So need system mobile timezone (local)

Comment: problem is here if my current time is 12:46 1st record is 01:00 i don't want next event i wan't running event and than after next to next event

Comment: you near by my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can ORDER BY by expression so just wrap your logic in simple expression using CASE, date time functions and you're good to go

Comment: Please give query

Comment: yes you near by the answer but i haven't knowledge about SQL so can't understand  your theory is write but i wan't query . (by the way thank you )